# Angular JS: all $scope is lost after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to reload the parent from the child, however after lunching the reload link I am loosing the id variable from the link which make a bug.

For example instead of getting "Entity/account/Details/224563" I am getting Entity/account/Details/ and the code that I am using:

```
 var accountstate = $myapp.findOverviewInjector().get("$state");
 var idEntity= parseInt($state.params.entityId);
 personstate.reload(accountstate.current, {id:idEntity}, { reload: true });
```

for extra details:

```
controller:"AccountDetailsCtrl"
name:"details"
params:{entity:"Acount"}
url:"/Entity/:entity/Details/:id?ids"
```

my question is how to call reload correctly without loosing the id
just to know in my case I need reload "$state.go" will not achieve my goal and I try it already.

```
$state.go(accountstate.current, { id: $state.params.entityId }, { reload: accountstate.current });
```

it works, but it does not achieve the goal

big thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is 
    $state.go(accountstate.current.current, { id: $state.params.entityId }, { reload: true });